# How to set mod_rewrite in WAMP?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I learn Symfony2 and i have:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/app.php/demo/hello/Fabien
```

> And if you use Apache with mod_rewrite enabled, you can even omit the
>   app.php part of the URL:

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/demo/hello/Fabien
```

> Last but not least, on the production servers, you should point your
>   web root directory to the web/ directory to secure your installation
>   and have an even better looking URL:

```
http://localhost/demo/hello/Fabien
```

how can i make this in WAMP Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is add a virtual host which points to the symfony application. You can do that by adding another virtual host with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    # Basic stuff
    DocumentRoot "C:/path/to/symfony/web"
    DirectoryIndex app.php
    <Directory "C:/path/to/symfony/web">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Depending on your configuration, you either have a httpd-vhosts.conf within your apache/conf/extra folder where you can add the part or you can add it to the httpd.conf! Make also sure no other virtual host for localhost is defined.

Comment: serverfault.com may not be the best place to ask question regards sf2 and since there isn't yet any efficient way to receive support with symfony 2 I think the following proposal is a very good idea! - [A new Q&A site for symfony2](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36634/symfony2) - Please join & spread the word!

Answer (score 2):

First you need to enable mod_rewrite in Xampp the way it says [here](http://rudyegenias.wordpress.com/2006/08/21/enabling-mod-rewrite-in-xampp/). Then you need to set a mod_rewrite rule in the .htaccess of your application typically in the "web" folder. A rule to remove the app.php would be like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

If you want to know more about URL Rewriting here is a nice [tutorial](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/).

Comment: thanks, but this is default in Symfony. how can i remove Symfony/web ?